# Building an app that rooting android device

Tags: android, android-studio, root, rooted-device

I want to create an application like "King Root" that root the android device by one click.
Is there a library or code for this?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a thing you can just do and if you could, it would mean that android would have a HUGE security breach, since with root access strangers could have unwanted access over the whole device, including banking information etc.
By the way: KingRoot does not work